# Work of weight force

Tags: definite-integrals, physics, inner-products, classical-mechanics

I'm trying calculating the work of weight force of a punctiform mass, free falling from an height L . We know that total work along the path is given by dot product between force and displacement, integrated all over the path. Then considering an ascendent z axis of a reference frame with origin on the ground, and integrating the dot product of force along small displacements dz, we have:

$$ W = \int_L^0   |-mg||dz|\cos(0) = \int_L^0   mg  |dz|  \cos(0) $$

First question: is $dz$ a real number, such as can I  transform $|dz|$ to $-dz$, assuming $dz < 0$ ?(fact that $dz < 0$ might be because mass is falling against the z axis’ direction, but I'm not sure we can make such kind of consideration).

If so, my integral would become:

$$ W = \int_L^0   mg  (-dz) = -\int_0^L   mg (-dz) = mg (L - 0) = mgL $$

Which is the correct answer since work W, when gravitational force is parallel and equiverse with respect to displacement, is positive. But is it my process correct to derive W?

**Are we allowed to treat infinitesimals as real numbers, and assign positive or negative signs to them?**

Comment: Hi @Glack_89 I have edited your post to improve formatting. Please check to see that the edits and the final line do not interfere with your query.

Comment: @insipidintegrator hi, yes, no problem, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since the positive direction for height is up, and the gravity is down, the angle between the two is $\pi$. So $$(m\vec g)\cdot d\vec z=mgdz\cos \pi=-mgdz$$
You wil get the right answer with your approach as well, but I think it's easier this way. Keep the directions consistent.

Comment: But the angle you are calculating the cosine, is not between the force of gravity and the positive direction of the height, as you computed (and in that case you would be right it's pi). It is between the force of gravity and the small movement dz of the mass, which is going against the increasing z axis!

Comment: $dz$ is positive in the positive $z$ direction. The fact that the object moves in the negative direction is accounted for by the limits of the integration. Think about an even simpler case: the displacement of an object moving along the $z$ axis is $$\int_{z_{initial}}^{z_{final}}dz=z_{final}-z_{initial}$$You can have $z_{final}$ greater or smaller than $z_{initial}$ and the formula still works.

Comment: So are you implying that dz is a real number? Anyway i don't know... the limits of integration only say where you start and where you arrive but don't tell about the verse of movement, in principle you could also have a work where you have dz movements that keep changing (going on and back, and this is accounted by cosine of the angle, which can vary) and eventually still have the same points of start and finish...